# Storing unknown datatype in MS SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does any one has an idea of whats the best practice to store an unknown data type in a table.
Basically I would need to store types like bit, smallint, int, real and nvarchar in the same "value" column, for later interpretation by a .NET application.

I was trying to achieve the best possible solution not to compromise the performance or growth of the database.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are going down the EAV route, I suggest you do some reading as to why this is a bad data structure in a relational database. see:http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/  If you really need to do this, you might consider a nosql solution instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Varchar(max) is probably the easiest way to do this.

sql_variant was designed for this purpose so you could use it, but read the Books Online entry to ensure it's going to do what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181071.aspx

Comment: I don't like much the varchar solution, but I'm definitely going to try the sql_variant and test the conversion performance hit. If it is acceptable, than that's going be the way it is! Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you only have two options:

You're object will have to be saved as some kind of string. That string could be a raw string or XML. If you "serialize" it as XML ans store it in the database, again, you can choose `nvarchar` or `XML`. I would point out that "serializing it" will bloat the data. If you can reasonably determine the data type based on another column that you may be pulling at the same time, then I would suggest just putting it in as a string.

Comment: The solution seems fine, but wouldn't the serialized string or Xml  be a lot bigger (in bytes) than base data itself?

Comment: @Guilherme, yes, which is why i said `'I would point out that "serializing it" will bloat the data'` But if you have no other way of determining the actual data type, this can be a fall-back.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'unknown type'. If you mean that a value is exactly one of a limited number of possible types then I would use a single-column -- strongly typed -- table for each possible type and a 'superclass' table to tell you which table to look in.

Comment: In fact that's precisely my current solution. But I was trying to enhance the table crossings, and select queries, by having a single "values" table. If there's is no other choice, that's the way it's going to stay.

Answer (score 0):

Store it as a [varchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258242%28SQL.80%29.aspx)  (or [nvarchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)).  This will handle all the types.  You will have to determine what length to make it based on what you know about your data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. but I was avoiding the varchar (nvarchar) solution because of database growth and conversions performance hit.

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too; if you want to store different types in the same column, what ***other*** type would you use? String/varchar is the **only** type that can represent all the other types (except binary, or course).

Comment: **Note: I just read down about the `sql_varient` type and that seems like a viable solution, but I wonder how .NET will react to casting the objects in that column to the type that you desire.

Comment: Well in fact my .NET solution already stores the value in an object property, so probably there's not going to be much castings.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
YourTableName
...more columns...
ColType char(1)       --B=bit, S=smallint, I=int, R=real, n=nvarchar, you can FK to a table to store these or just check constraint them
Col     nvarchar(x)   --where x is large enought to hold your longest string or other value
...more columns...
```

in the .Net app, read in `ColType` and convert the `Col` column to that type.  When saving, SQL Server will convert the native data types to the nvarchar() for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. but I was avoiding the varchar (nvarchar) solution because of database growth and conversions performance hit.

Comment: ha, your selected answer: "sql_variant" how do you think that will perform better?